# create a new object from the base interface of another object c#

Tags: c#, interface

I am trying to create a new object from the base interface of another object.

**IDailyEventBase** is the base interface of ***currentEvent*** and also the base interface of **DailyEventEntity**.

Is there a way to create new **DailyEventEntity** object from ***currentEvent*** object without re-assigning all shared base properties values again?

```
private bool CreateDailyEvent(EventDefinitionEntity eventApp
        ,IDailyEventBase currentEvent)
    {
        //create daily event
        DailyEventEntity dailyEvent = iDailyEvent as DailyEventEntity;
```

Comment: You implement interfaces, not create objects from them.

Comment: If you need exactly DailyEventEntity object inside your method why don't you pass it as a second parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to keep an existing object (of a some type, that implements an interface) and wrap ("decorate") it into another object that implements some other additional interface. This is possible by "aggregating" existing object and delegating all methods of that interface to inner object.

This is sample of how class can delegate implementation to existing object:

```
interface IDailyEventBase 
{
    void MethodOne();
}

class SomeEvent : IDailyEventBase ...

class DailyEventEntity : IDailyEventBase 
{
   IDailyEventBase inner;
   public DailyEventEntity(IDailyEventBase inner)
   {
       this.inner = inner;
   }

   public void MethodOne() 
   {
      // delegate directly to wrapped class. You can also add more code here.
      return inner.MethodOne();
   }

   // other methods of this class (may use properties of "inner" too)
   public void OtherMethod()...
}
```

And usage sample:

```
IDailyEventBase other = new SomeEvent();
var delegatingDailyEvent = new DailyEventEntity(other);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an object from an interface.

Having said that you can instantiate an object of the base *class* of an object using reflection.

Something like that:

```
var o = Activator.CreateObject(this.GetType().BaseType);
```

Answer (score 0):

currentEvent implementing IDailyEventBase interface, but you can't assign it to DailyEventEntity class until it not the same type or type derived from DailyEventEntity.

And I'm not recommending you to do this actions inside CreateDailyEvent method because somebody can create class that implements IDailyEventBase and pass object of this class to your your method what will get you InvalidCastException in runtime.